# How do you make a floating sidebar like envato?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I really like the floating panel on the left side of the following site:

http://envato.com/

I have no idea what its called, but I like how when you click on the search button, it expands to a search page, you click on another icon, and it expands with what appears like its own page.

How do I accomplish this? Is there some tutorial out there using html5, JavaScript or jQuery?

NOTE: All the answers so far only cover the floating bar, but not the clicking on a link on that floating bar to show a window expanded to the right.

Comment: Just a note: I really *don't* like this feature. It's awkward, unintuitive, and I can't access some of the links because of the fixed position. I'd consider it a UI failure. Your users may feel the same way.

Answer (score 12):

```
<div id="float"></div>

#float{
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/TVwAv/

Answer (score 4):

done using css,

**HTML**

```
<div id="floating_sidebar">
 whatever you want to put here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#floating_sidebar {
 position:fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 100px; /* change to adjust height from the top of the page */
}
```

Comment: `position:absolute` will not work. it will scroll down with the page. For the div to stay in place when scrolling, you need to you `position:fixed`

Answer (score 4):

I am using this for a "floating (sticky) menu". 
What I have added is:
 1. to avoid my 'footer' always being "scrolled" down in case the sidemenu is a little high, I only do the scrolling if necessary, i.e -
 when the content is higher than the sidebar.
 2. I found the animate effect a little "jumpy" to my taste, so I just changed the css through jquery. of-course you put a 0 in the animate time, but the animation still occurs, so it's cleaner and faster to use the css.
 3. 100 is the height of my header. you can assume it to be the "threshold" of when to do the scrolling.

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($('#sidebar').height() < $('#content').height())
    {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 90)
        $('#sidebar').css({"margin-top": ($(this).scrollTop()) - 100 });
        //$('#sidebar').animate({"marginTop": ($(this).scrollTop()) - 100 }, 0);
    else
        $('#sidebar').css({"margin-top": ($(this).scrollTop()) });
        //$('#sidebar').animate({"marginTop": ($(this).scrollTop()) }, 0);
    }
 });`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this ..

your html div is here

```
<div id="scrolling_div">Your text here</div>
```

And you javascript function is here

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#scrolling_div').stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(this).scrollTop()) +10+ "px"}, "slow"});
    });
```

You can also use the css for this

```
#scrolling_div {
 position:absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 100px; 
}
```

I have not tested it but hopefully its worked.

Comment: Overkill. `position: fixed` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I know this looks quite a big piece of code, however this function just works by specifying three simple options; your floater "top", your "target" (floater) and "reference" element to set the boundaries, it also takes care of the top and bottom position automatically, no css involved.

```
function scrollFloater(marginTop, reference, target, fixWhidth = false){

  var processScroll = function(){
    var from = reference.offset().top - marginTop;
    var to = reference.offset().top + reference.outerHeight() + marginTop - target.outerHeight();
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var bottom = to - reference.offset().top + marginTop;

    if( fixWhidth )
      target.css('width', target.width());

    if( scrollTop > from && scrollTop < to )
      target.css('position', 'fixed').css('top',marginTop);
    else if( scrollTop >= to )
      target.css('position', 'absolute').css('top', bottom);
    else
      target.css('position', '').css('top',marginTop);

  }

  $(window).scroll(function(){ processScroll(); });
  processScroll();

}
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
$(function() {
    scrollFloater(41, $('.box.auth.register'), $('.plans-floater'), true);
});
```

I hope this helps someone.